# Is it possible to transfer a file from a Linux Bash script to Windows without mounting the server folder?

Tags: shell, networking, smb

I am writing a script (Bash) to transfer files from my local Linux machine to Windows servers.
The Windows servers are accessible normally using the [SAMBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) shares, and I am able to mount a folder to my Linux machine using the `mount.cifs` command with the proper Windows credentials.

Because I do not want to mount every server in advance nor mounting dynamically using `sudo` (the script is executed as a normal user, not root), I am just wondering if the server can be accessed by another means, like a [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) pipe or a similar way.

For example, under Windows I can mount my server's folder to a drive letter using the [net use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_use) command, but as well without having being mounted like this:

```
c:> net use \\my-server.domain.com passwd123 /user:domain\myuser
c:> cp d:\myfiles.zip \\my-server.domain.com\d$\temp\destination
```

And if I make a `net use`, I can see the open connection (without letter assigned):

```
    Status       Local     Remote                    Network
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK                     \\myserver.domain.net\IPC$
                                                Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

I do not want to install sshd nor ftpd on the Windows Server. I am looking to do it only with the [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) protocol. As a fallback I will execute a mount like `sudo mount.cifs [options] /mnt/temp-folder` and `sudo umount /tmp/temp-folder` after the copy of the files.

Comment: What you can do on the Windows server depends intrinsically on what services are running on it. If you were running an sshd, e.g., you could scp a file. If you had nc, you could have it listen on a port and redirect it straight into the output filename. &c. &c.

Comment: What about using putty on the windows side? Putty will allow a windows machine to ssh and call a command, as well as scp. That would enable you to trigger the script and copy the results using the windows server. There might also be a tools that goes the opposite direction, a linux tools that lets you transfer to windows instead of a windows tool that lets you transfer to/from linux.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `smbclient` program to give you an FTP-like interface to the Windows file share without having to install FTP on the Windows machine.

Here follows some examples:

*Transfer file from local (unix/linux) to Windows:*

```
smbclient //server.domain.org/d$ <password> -W domain.org -U <my-user> -c "put file-local.xml folder1\folder2\file.xml"
```

*Transfer file from Windows to Linux:*

There are two options, the first is using the command 'get' with `smbclient` and a the second, a shortest one: `smbget`:

```
1. smbclient: `smbclient //server.domain.org/d$ <password> -W domain.org -U <my-user> -c "get folder1\folder2\file.xml file-local.xml"`
2. smbget: `smbget -u <my-user> -p <password> -w domain.org -o destination-file.txt smb://server.domain.org/d$/folder1/folder2/source-file.txt`
```

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I was looking for. I just updated your answer with practical examples.

Answer (score 2):

You might try something like `wput [options] [file]... [url]... ftp://[username[:password]@]hostname[:port][/[path/][file]]`
 or `wget`